# Android Studio Method createUserWithEmailAndPassword() from Firebase doesn't do anything

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The idea is when the user register it goes to another screen.It is supposed to work but I doesn't add any user to the Firebase and there is a block if where it should tell me if it work or not but that doesn't work either. I get the code for a video tutorial, then I placed the ones that Firebase give you and nothing.

This is the code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText tName,
            tEmail,
            tPassword;

    private Button bCreateAccount;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        tName = findViewById(R.id.fill_name);
        tEmail = findViewById(R.id.fill_email);
        tPassword = findViewById(R.id.fill_password);
        bCreateAccount = findViewById(R.id.button_create_account);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        bCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = tName.getText().toString();
                String email = tEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = tPassword.getText().toString();


                createAccount(email,password,name);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAccount(String email, String password, String name) {

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"You got some error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Code seems to be correct. Did you check errors in log ? Try to throw exception in else.

Comment: Did you enabled the email auth inside the firebase auth consol ???

Comment: @Arga, Have you enabled the Email auth in firebase console ?

Comment: Well today I used again and it worked even when I didn't change anything. Thanks to everyone